# Better way to include custom fields from user table in JWT claim in laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am using `tymon/jwt-auth` liibrary for `JWT authentication` in my project which is built using `laravel`.

In my mysql `users` table I am having a `role_id` column. I want to include that in my generated `JWT token's claim` on login so that I can implement role based `ACL` using my JWT token on subsquent requests.

Below is what I have tried to get it working

```
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $userModel = User::where('email',$request->input('email'))->get()->first();
    $role = $userModel->roles_id;
    $customClaim = ['role' => $role];

    try 
    {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, $customClaim)) 
        {
            //return 401 error
        }
    } 
    catch (JWTException $e) 
    {
        //return 500 error
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

Above code is working fine as expected but problem with above code is on login I have to hit my `database` twice once for getting role and one for authenticating user. That would be great if someone can suggest a better way to do it in a single database hit.